# Vuejs - Router doesn't render third component in app. First two are working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-router

I created my first Vue app and I have a problem with the router. I have 3 components first 2 works perfectly but 3 doesn't. Here is my code:

`index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Homepage from '@/components/Homepage'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import Register from '@/components/Register'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Homepage',
      component: Homepage
    },
    {
      path: '/account/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/account/register',
      name: 'Register',
      compontent: Register
    }
  ]
})
```

`Register.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h2>This is test</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
  name: 'Register',
  data () {
    return {
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h1, h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried to use Register.vue in login rout and it worked. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help!

If it matters I run sever by `npm run dev`.

Comment: Do you have any error log? What happens when you visit `/account/register` directly by entering url to browser?

Comment: I have a blank white page without any error in console.

Comment: Is your Register.vue file in the right directory?

Comment: @JegadeshBS Yeah I have it in same directory as Login and Homepage

Comment: @xaos_xv why are you importing Vue again in the component(Register.vue) ?

Comment: @JegadeshBS Yes I think, all I have in my code is in my post.

Comment: I mean can you try removing `import Vue from 'vue'` from Register component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the property `compontent` to `component`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I feel so stupid that I didn't see this.